# Retrieve history of past kafka consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there a way to get a list of consumers (IPs) which connected to the broker as member of a given consumer group?

I know the kafka-consumer-group.sh command does this for all currently connected/active consumers. 
But I am interested if there was a temporary consumer eg 5 minutes ago, which did consume some of the messages in a topic.

I had also tried to increase logging on authorizer to debug. But the result were millions of additional logs in a few hours.

Thanks, jochen

Answer (score 1):

Try AdminClient with  listConsumerGroups to get consumer list

```
/*List the consumer groups available in the cluster with the default options.*/
public ListConsumerGroupsResult listConsumerGroups() {
        return listConsumerGroups(new ListConsumerGroupsOptions());
    }
```

Below sample to get list of consumers

```
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
    iomport org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;

    AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(props);
    //.all(): Returns a future that yields either an exception, or the full set of consumer group listings.
    List<String> listConsumer=client.listConsumerGroups().all().get().stream().
    map(f -> f.groupId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: from what i am seeing, this only prints the 'active' consumers.